# PowerShell Export-Excel Conditional Formatting if date > 30 days

Tags: excel, powershell

I know that I can use code like the following to format date columns for the prior month.  Is there a way to conditionally format a column if the date is > 30 days?

```
$LastLogonInfo |
  Export-Excel $OutputFile -WorksheetName 'LastLogonInfo' -AutoFilter -BoldTopRow`
               -FreezeTopRow -AutoSize`
               -ConditionalText $(New-ConditionalText -ConditionalType LastMonth)
```

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just try to convert column with lastLogonData in LastLogonInfo list to number of days, and later try to use

```
New-ConditionalText -ConditionalType GreaterThan
```

I am afraid that Excel in conditional formating allows only specific predefined ranges, like is described here: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/06/17/excel-conditional-formatting-dates/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the following to work for a conditional format of logon dates older than 90 days. Excel will read the '=now()-90' as a conditional formatting formula, and highlight any values that are 90 days older than the time the script is run.

```
$CTXT = New-ConditionalText -Text '=now()-90' -ConditionalType LessThan

$LastLogonInfo |
  Export-Excel $OutputFile -WorksheetName 'LastLogonInfo' -AutoFilter -BoldTopRow  
               -FreezeTopRow -AutoSize -ConditionalText $CTXT
```